# Serving django with nginx and uWSGI

Tags: nginx, python, django, uwsgi

I followed [this post](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) to serve my django project. The project runs well with `manage.py runserver` and I want to set it up for production. Here are my setting files:

`nginx.conf`:

```
upstream django {
    server /tmp/vc.sock;
    #server 10.9.1.137:8002;
}

server {
    listen      8001;
    server_name 10.9.1.137;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 25M;

    location /media  {
        alias /home/deploy/vc/media;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/deploy/vc/static;
    }


    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

`uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]

chdir           = /home/deploy/vc
wsgi-file      = vc/wsgi.py

master          = true
processes       = 2
#socket          = :8002
socket          = /tmp/vc.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
```

If I use TCP port socket (`server 10.9.1.137:8002` and `socket = :8002`), it's going to be fine. However if I comment them out and use Unix sockets(`server /tmp/vc.sock` and `socket = /tmp/vc.sock`), the server will return 502 error. How should I fix it?

Here's the nginx error log when I run `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "/tmp/vc.sock" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/vc.conf:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

And this is the warning when I run `uwsgi --ini vc/uwsgi.ini`:

```
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
```

Can't I run uWSGI as root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [`upstream` `server`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server) which uses a Unix domain socket must be declared as such:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:/tmp/vc.sock;
```

And yes, I suppose you *could* run uWSGI as root, but [you absolutely positively should not](https://serverfault.com/q/155976/126632). This is security 101. The uWSGI project even go so far as to [call it common sense](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html):

> Common sense: do not run uWSGI instances as root. You can start your uWSGIs as root, but be sure to drop privileges with the `uid` and `gid` options.

---

BTW, your `server` block could use a `root` directive. That would let you get rid of those pointless redundant `location`s for your static assets.

```
    root /home/deploy/vc;
```